# GridFS and standard collections, memory usage

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, nosql

As I know, MongoDB is optimized for situation when all data fits into memory. And as I understood GridFS uses standard collection and all standard storage methods. Is it?

Does it mean that storing a large set of data (images at my case), that bigger that current amount of memory, it will forse out my real data from memory?

Maybe MongoDB smart enough to give less priority for GridFS collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB uses memory-mapped files to manage its data files. If you use data, it will stay in memory. If you don't use it, it will eventually be flushed to disk (and be read back, when you request it next time). If you need to read all your data, you better fit it all in RAM or your  system might enter the deadly swap spiral (depends on your load, of course).

If you just store data and don't do much with it, MongoDB will use only a fraction of memory. For example, in one of my projects total dataset size is over 300 GB and mongo takes only 800 MB of RAM (because I almost don't read data, only write it).

Comment: The problem that most of this images will be used very often :( Maybe i'm wrong, and need to gather some stats. It's why i'm asking, i hoped that there is an optimization for this case. Ok, I got your answer, thanks.